# Konva rendering only one layer when sending more through a for loop

Tags: angular, typescript, konvajs, konva

I am getting a hall from the backend with sectors and the sectors contain seats. When I try render the entire hall at once it works, but I have to separate different types of sectors and when I try to render them separately, only one sector shows up on the screen.

This is the method that renders the seats to the screen. The parameter is all of the seats in one sector. The math is not that important because the seats don't show up at all.

```
renderSeats(seats: Seat[]) {
    const stage = new Konva.Stage({
      container: this.stageContainer.nativeElement,
      width: 800,
      height: 400
    });

    const layer = new Konva.Layer();
    stage.add(layer);

    const seatWidth = 40;
    const seatHeight = 40;
    const seatMargin = 10;

    seats.forEach((seat) => {
      const { seatNumber, seatRow, id, seatSector } = seat;

      const uniqueValues = new Set(this.sectorIds);
      const modSize = uniqueValues.size;
      
      const offset = (sectorIndex % modSize) * rowLength;
      const seatX = (offset + seatNumber) * (seatWidth + seatMargin);
      const seatY = seatRow * (seatHeight + seatMargin);

      const seatRect = new Konva.Rect({
        x: seatX,
        y: seatY,
        width: seatWidth,
        height: seatHeight,
        fill: 'white',
      });
      layer.add(seatRect);
    });
    layer.batchDraw();
  }
```

These methods provide the seats to the above method.

```
getSeatInSector(sectorId: number) {
    this.sectorService.getSeatsBySectorId(sectorId).subscribe({
      next: (seats: Seat[]) => {
        this.seats = seats;
        this.renderSeats(seats);
      }
    });
  }

getSectorsByHallId(hallId: number) {
   this.hallplanService.getSectorsByHallId(hallId).subscribe({
    next: (sectors: Sector[]) => {
      this.sectorIds = sectors.map(sector => sector.id);
      this.sectorIds.forEach((id) => {
        this.getSeatInSector(id);
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: I figured it out. Every time I go into the method I make a new Konva Stage and it gets redrawn from scratch. I put it outside of the method and it works now.